# What is the best way to CRUD Cassandra cluster from C# app

Tags: c#, nosql, cassandra, thrift, datastax-enterprise

I've been looking around the net for a while, what is the best way to CRUD (create, remove, update, delete) cassandra cluster/keyspaces/column families & columns in general?

There are many frameworks & drivers & api (thrift, hector, datastax driver, cassandra sharp driver, aquiles, fluentcassandra...) and I'm really confused on which one to choose.

Can anybody give a small resume/overview on the best way to do such a thing ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

There is no best way in general, it all depends on what you want to do.

I would suggest the [datastax .NET driver](https://github.com/datastax/csharp-driver) because it is getting developed as we speak and if you see something you dont like or want to request a feature you can do so through the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!forum/csharp-driver-user) and the even better reason, there is an IRC channel (look at the driver's github) where you can ask questions if you need some help.

As far as CRUD goes, you can use CQL3 queries which are similar to SQL, and the driver even has some LINQ support.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [Cassandra .Net driver and CQL driver (Aug 2012)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11855629/cassandra-net-driver-and-cql-driver-aug-2012)

seems like FluentCassandra is pretty good. It has Linq2CQL support, and after getting to know Linq2Sql few years ago, i don't really like to write too many SqlCommands anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There are different layers, the highest level drivers are abstractions of the Thrift layer (easier to use), you could also use directly the Thrift protocol (you have more control, but it is more complex).

I would recommend you the driver from Datastax, they make the official support of Cassandra and they really take care of it.